# How to get various SCM options in Jenkins Version 2.46.3

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, java-7

I need to point to the code which is on my machine , i installed Jenkins 2.46.3 on tomcat 8 and running on jdk 7, I am unable to find the right plugin to point to my source code. Please help

Currently i see only option as None.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins

View the "Available" tab and choose the appropriate SCM plugin such as Git Plugin or SVN Plugin based on what your SCM tool is.